# Filling a dataTable with data from another one using jQuery in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I use CodeIgniter and I have two dataTables (in two separate views. same js, model and controller files)

I can fill the first table with a SELECT query and it works normally.

My problem is that I need data (for the query) from the first table (using a click to select which row) to fill the second one. I couldn't make it work yet. I already executed the required SELECT query in phpMyAdmin and it works.

controller file

```
function refreshT2(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $id = stripslashes($id);
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $this->load->model('model');
    $data=$this->model->getAllById($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

js file

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $("#table1").addClass("started");
    $("#table2").addClass("started");

    var t1Source = "controller/refreshT1";
    var t2Source = "controller/refreshT2";

    var oTablet1=$('#table1').dataTable({
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI":true,
        "sDom": 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        "sAjaxSource": ft1Source
    });

    $("#table1 tbody").click(function(event) {
        var iPos=oTablet1.fnGetPosition(event.target.parentNode);
        var aData=oTablet1.fnGetData(iPos);

        var id=aData[2];

        $('input[name=id]').val(id);
    /* When I click on the first dataTable the field 'id' is filled properly */

        var oTableft2 = $('#table2').dataTable({
            "sScrollX": "100%",
            "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
            "bJQueryUI":true,
            "sDom": 'R<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "sAjaxSource": t2Source
        });
    } );
}
```

If I need to provide more information/code please tell me.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT: when I switch `$id = $_POST['id'];` with a real value it works. How can I retrieve this data?

I don't want to use a "button+action" solution. If it works inside the js I won't need any send/receive method. what I need is how to pass a parameter to the second table.

Comment: your problem is pass the value from server side right?

Comment: lets debug it for you, is your click on table1's row working properly, and is the data / id that you are sending to server for other view to update being received properly. if yes, then what's coming our from db, and what format, then are you being able to parse and bind it with table2?   debug it

Comment: I just found out that the problem lies in the {$id = $_POST['id'];} part. I switched it to a real value and it worked

Comment: It seems that I need to pass my id using another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to add the id to the link in `sAjaxSource` like this:

```
"sAjaxSource": t2Source+"?id="+id
```

and use `$_GET` and not `$_POST` in my controller.

Comment: here is a sample cms that uses datatables with server side processing for your reference . https://github.com/gencms/sample-gencms/